# Why can't Excel 365 vba save my pdf file?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I think now I tried nearly everything to save a pdf file with Excel vba.

This is my actual code:

```
Dim pdfFile As String

If excel2016 Then
    pdfFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "/Report_" & year & month & "_" & Replace(name, " ", "_") & ".pdf"
Else
    pdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Report_" & year & month & "_" & Replace(name, " ", "_") & ".pdf"
End If

wsOutputOne.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=pdfFile
```

I know that Excel 2016 is creating a "container" and saving the files under `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/` but why does that code not work with Excel 365?

Or what has a friend with Excel 365 to do to save this generated pdf file?
Because the call of `Application.DefaultFilePath` returns nothing on his machine...

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't search for articles that use Excel 365 VBA to save PDF file. Wsoutputone is Worksheet object?

Comment: yes of course this is a worksheet.

Comment: any one any idea that could help?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why not just use the workbook path?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
Dim pdfFile As String

If excel2016 Then
  pdfFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "/Report_" & year & month & "_" & Replace(name, " ", "_") & ".pdf"
Else
  pdfFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Report_" & year & month & "_" & Replace(name, " ", "_") & ".pdf"
End If

wsOutputOne.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=pdfFile
```

Comment: thanks! but unfortunately your code changes are only in the "!ecxel2016" part. using this with an old excel version works. but using it with (some) excel 365 doesn't work.